# Countdown in Javascript don't work correctly in IE

Tags: javascript, countdown

I found a countdown in JavaScript, but for some reason it doesn't work correctly in IE11.

The code is:

```
var now = new Date();
var current_year = now.getFullYear();
var next_year = current_year + 1;

var target_date = new Date("May 18, " + current_year).getTime();

var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

var $days = document.getElementById("d");
var $hours = document.getElementById("h");
var $minutes = document.getElementById("m");
var $seconds = document.getElementById("s");

function update() {
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

    $days.innerHTML = pad(days, 2);
    $hours.innerHTML = pad(hours, 2);
    $minutes.innerHTML = pad(minutes, 2);
    $seconds.innerHTML = pad(seconds, 2);
}


update();

setInterval(update, 1000);

function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}
```

When i change the date to a specific hour in that day, like:

```
var target_date = new Date("May 18, 2014 12:00:00" + current_year).getTime();
```

I can see correctly the countdown in Chrome and Mozilla, but in IE11(and maybe the lower versions) it appears NaN (Not a number).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This error usually occurs when you perform an arithmetic operation with a variable that does not contain a number. Check your datatypes, a string that contains "10" may not be considered the same as an integer with value 10 at some places and that might throw this error.

Comment: @Merlin Denker  But the Javascript don't work ONLY on IE, so the code is correct. If not, Chrome/Mozilla couldn't show it correctly... Don't you think?

Comment: Yeah but if you want to support old IE versions you will have to find a workaround. check my answer, I think I found the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `var target_date = new Date(2014,4,18,12,0,0).getTime();` (note the zero-based month). That should work in all browsers. Works for me in IE11: http://jsfiddle.net/bCYU9/1/ (Your `new Date("May 18, 2014 12:00:00" + current_year)` doesn't really make sense because it has the year specified twice.)

Comment: @nnnnnn That's it! I already tried that, but i left the current_year, but now i use literally your line and it works perfectly in all browsers. U can use it as an answer for this question.

Comment: _"U can use it as an answer for this question"_ - OK, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `new Date("May 18, 2014 12:00:00" + current_year)` doesn't really make sense because it specifies a year *twice* - once as the literal 2014 in the middle of the string and once with whatever is in `current_year`.

But aside from that, I guess IE isn't as flexible about what date string formats it accepts, so to be safe you could specify all the date parts separately (note that the month is zero-based):

```
var target_date = new Date(current_year,4,18,12,0,0).getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in this line:

```
var s = num+"";
```

num is an integer and you tell JS to add (not concat) a string. Strings cannot be added to integers... You need to convert num to a string before concatinating or user another method to combine num and the empty string.

To convert a number into a string you should use:

```
number.toString();
```

Comment: This code is not mine. It was sent to me, and when i changed the date parameter, IE didnt' show me the numbers, but Chrome/Safari for some reason show... I have another countdown that works perfectly, but they insisted on this one...

Comment: Just change the false line to var s = num.toString(); and I guess you will be fine.

Comment: It shows me nothing now in IE. After a while it shows me NaN again. This code takes too much time to load...

Comment: _"Strings cannot be added to integers"_ - If you have `num+""` JS in all browsers will automatically convert `num` to a string and then concatenate `""`. Adding an empty string is a common way to convert a number to a string.

Comment: I've had trouble with doing it that way quite a couple of times, so I would prefer the clean way of using `.toString()`

Comment: If you prefer `.toString()` that's fine for your code, but it is incorrect to say that `num+""` won't work. The ECMAScript specification explicitly indicates that you can concatenate a string onto a number and get a string as the result.

Comment: @MerlinDenker - With this code "function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num.toString();
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}" i get the countdown correctly in Chrome but in IE it shows me NaN again...